# Проблема во время настройки NDK в AdroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

Я пытаюсь настроить NDK, но имеются некоторые затруднения.

Первым делом в `SDKTools` я установил всё, что было связано с NDK.

[image: SDKTools #1]

[image: SDKTools #2]

Но студия выдаёт ошибку `ERROR: CMake '3.10.2' was not found in PATH or by cmake.dir property.`

Чтобы её исправить я установил `CMake 3.10.2` в `D:\AndroidStudioCMake\cmake-3.10.2-win32-x86\bin` и добавил путь до исполняемого файла в `Переменные среды` (получилось `D:\AndroidStudioCMake\cmake-3.10.2-win32-x86\bin\cmake.exe`). Если добавлять как `D:\AndroidStudioCMake\cmake-3.10.2-win32-x86\bin`, то ошибка остаётся, также ошибка остаётся, если в файле `local.properties` добавить строчку `cmake.dir=D\:\\AndroidStudioCMake\\cmake-3.10.2-win32-x86\\bin\\cmake.exe`.

**UPD:** Я понял, что `AndroidStudio` работает только с `CMake`, предназначенным для 64 битных систем, поэтому придётся или переходить на 64 bit, или продолжать писать на SDK.

Comment: А у вас `SDK Manager` нет пункта `CMake`? Дело в том что нужен ещё  toolchain файл для андроида и студия наверняка всё это ищет в папке SDK. https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake. Если не получится исправить - студия всё ещё поддерживает `ndk-build`: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-build

Comment: Огромное спасибо за наводку, @woesss! В моём случае в `SDK Manager` пункта `CMake` не было, сделал через `ndk-build`. Скачал с [официального сайта](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases?hl=fi) версию r20b и сделал как в [этом](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0vL7-_xuDM) видео.

Comment: Сначала при компиляции библиотек у меня возникала ошибка `Android NDK: APP_PLATFORM not set. Defaulting to minimum supported version android-16.`, в этом случае надо в файл `jni/Application.mk` добавить строчку `APP_PLATFORM := android-16`.